# Mutable iterator

Tags: rust, iterator, lifetime

I am trying to write a mutable iterator over a vector, but I am unable to figure out what the compiler is trying to tell me. Here is my implementation

```
struct IterMut<'a> {
    vec: &'a mut Vec<u32>,
    index: usize,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for IterMut<'a> {
    type Item = &'a mut u32;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let item = if self.index < self.vec.len() {
            Some(&mut self.vec[self.index])
        } else {
            None
        };

        self.index += 1;

        item
    }
}
```

And the compiler error is:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:60:9
   |
48 | impl<'a> Iterator for IterMut<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
51 |     fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
   |             - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
60 |         item
   |         ^^^^ associated function was supposed to return data with lifetime `'a` but it is returning data with lifetime `'1`
```

The non mutable version compiles and works.

```
struct Iter<'a> {
    vec: &'a Vec<u32>,
    index: usize,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for Iter<'a> {
    type Item = &'a u32;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let item = if self.index < self.vec.len() {
            Some(&self.vec[self.index])
        } else {
            None
        };

        self.index += 1;

        item
    }
}
```

[Here is a playground link with the code to try out.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4a2bae497c70fa6c43f7f3ba8710cfd8)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `IterMut` holds on to the elements already passed.

It can do so only by reborrowing the item but this now means that the item isn't borrowed from the original `Vec` any more but from the `IterMut` instead so it does not live long enough. (The reborrow only lives as long as the `IterMut`, not as long as the original `Vec`.

In nightly or once `take_first_mut` stabilizes you can do this:

```rust
#![feature(slice_take)]
struct IterMut<'a> {
    vec: &'a mut [u32],
}

impl<'a> Iterator for IterMut<'a> {
    type Item = &'a mut u32;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.vec.take_first_mut()
    }
}
```

Note I switched from `&mut Vec<u32>` to a slice because you have to be able to 'release' the items which is not easy with a `Vec`

---

As @ChayimFriedman pointed out on stable you can do it with `mem::take` in the meantime:

```rust
struct IterMut<'a> {
    vec: &'a mut [u32],
}

impl<'a> Iterator for IterMut<'a> {
    type Item = &'a mut u32;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let (first, rem) = std::mem::take(&mut self.vec).split_first_mut()?;
        self.vec = rem;
        Some(first)
    }
}
```